# How to extract URL links if the webpage contains more than one pages?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to extract URL links for selected section from Blogspot.

Unfortunately, when I run my codes, it only extracts the URL for the first page and ignore others.

For example there are 9 url links and 2 pages in http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/

But this codes can only extract 7 url links in the 1st page and ignore others url links in the next page.

Codes:

```
import urllib2 # Please look into the requests library
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Renaming your variables
links_file = open("link.txt")
# No need to split them yourself, theres a method for that
links = link_file.readlines() 


for url in links:
    htmltext = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)

    # describe your actions with variable names
    relative_tags_to_desired_links = soup.find_all("h3", "post-title entry-title", "name")

    for tag in relative_tags_to_desired_links:
        desired_element = tag.next_element.next_element
        print desired_element.get("href")
```

'link.txt' contains list of url (eg):

```
http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/
```

Output:

```
 http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/2011/03/my-vintage-pre-wedding.html
 http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/2011/02/pre-wedding-vintage.html
 http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/2010/12/tissue-paper-flower-crepe-paper.html
 http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/2010/12/menguap-menurut-islam.html
 http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/2010/12/weddings-idea.html
 http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/2010/12/kawin.html
 http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/2010/11/vitamin-c-collagen.html
```

So, could you help me on how to read all the pages from the Blogspot?

Thank you.

Comment: updated: 'link.txt' : contain a lists] of url link http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/

Comment: agreed, can't do much without the `link.txt`. Also when using `BeautifulSoup` what variables are holding can get confusing, for sanities sake and good programming, variable should describe the code.

Comment: You only open **ONE** url link, the output seems correct.

Comment: Ya I put only one url link as example. What I mean is this codes cannot read other pages inside that particular web/ url link. So it only extract the url in the first page. 
For example:

URL: http://ellywonderland.blogspot.com/ contains 2 pages and 9 links. But this codes can only extract 7 links in the first page and ignore others. @LittleQ

Comment: Could you explain `contains 2 pages`? I found only 7 matched href in the source code of the web page.

Comment: What I mean is: in the blogspot we can post many entry. Each entry will has it own url link. User can choose how many entry will appear on each page. In this case user choose to post 7 entry (7 url links) in one page. If reader want to read other entry they need to click "older post" link at the bottom. So, as mentioned, this code can only read the links at Page 1 only and ignore other entry/url links that are important to extract. @LittleQ

Comment: So you should `urlopen` "older post" link to extract what you want... You have already known the next step but forgot to realize it in your code...